# Using JsonSanitizer for Java Objects

Tags: json, sanitization

We need to sanitize a Json which is received as Java Object as shown in the below example

```java
@Path("/agent”)
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addAgent(Agent agent) throws Exception {}
```

We used JsonSanitizer for the purpose. However, JsonSanitizer accepts only String, so I had to convert my **agent** object to Json String, sanitize it and then convert back to **agent** object.

Is there an equivalent API which can sanitize Java Object directly without requiring the intermediate String conversion or any better approach than the one we took

Comment: What do you expect JSON sanitizer to do to an *Agent*?

Comment: I want to sanitize the object Agent - this is being flagged in checkMarx report with the comment - This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user .

Comment: How might an unsanitized *Agent* differ from a sanitized *Agent*?  The [sanitizer docs](https://github.com/OWASP/json-sanitizer#output) explain what the sanitizer does.  I'm not sure that JSON-sanitizing something that's already been parsed will help you present safe HTML to the user.

Comment: Agent is an object so it is composed of strings and other types. I think an unsantized agent will have its strings and other fields unsantized. Can you explain why object which has already been parsed need not be sanitized.

Comment: What do you mean by "sanitized?"

Comment: Sanitized would mean data fixed missing punctuation, end quotes, and mismatched or missing close brackets. If an input contains only white-space then the valid JSON string null is substituted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176480/discussion-between-vjm-and-mike-samuel).

Comment: @vjm Any solution ? I am also facing same issue -  flagged in checkMarx report with the comment - This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user

Answer (score -1):

JsonSanitizer is not the tool you need.

It ensures that the output is embeddable and evalable but does not trim whitespace or check balancedness of quotes within a string literal.